# How to export data into cdv from GemFire

Tags: gemfire

I am trying to build a ETL process that extracts data out to GemFire and load in Teradata. However, I am not finding a good mechanism to export data out. The only thing I have found so far is rest api that gets all entries from a region. However, is this good for bulk export ? It will give data back in json which has to be parsed before loading in table, which I assume won't be very performant for large volume of data. Is there any other solution to this ? Like exporting data as csv from GemFire? Or ODBC/JDBC connection to GemFire ? I found both the bulk export and ODBC/JDBC in Gemfire XD documentation but not in core GemFire? So are they not supported in core GemFire? What is the difference between core GemFire and the XD version ?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different products designed with different things in mind. GemFire XD provides a low-latency SQL interface to in-memory table data, so it's generally used as an in-memory RDBMS. GemFire, on the other hand, is an in-memory data grid with "no restrictions" regarding the data you insert into the regions, you basically deal with custom java objects, not with tables. Also, I know GemFire XD was built on top of GemFire in the past, not sure what's the current status of that (you might want to have a look at [Snappy Data](https://www.snappydata.io/) for more details).

That said, and strictly speaking of GemFire, you can export snapshots of your regions and import them afterwards into another cluster. Even better, you can read a snapshot entry by entry for further processing or transformation into other formats, which I believe is exactly what you're looking for. Please have a look at [Cache and Region Snapshots](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/managing/cache_snapshots/chapter_overview.html) to get the details.

Hope this helps. Cheers.